# Can you setup an azure server to sync with a outside NTP server?

Tags: azure

I'm trying to correct some time drift we're seeing in out azure servers, mentioned in this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2010/11/19/time-synchronization-in-hyper-v.aspx).  Has anyone been able to setup an azure server to sync with a NTP server outside of the azure cloud?  From what I've read NTP uses UDP which can be block in azure.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here are the steps I used

reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\TimeProviders\VMICTimeProvider /v Enabled /t reg_dword /d 0

w32tm /config /syncfromflags:manual /manualpeerlist:0.pool.ntp.org,1.pool.ntp.org,2.pool.ntp.org,3.pool.ntp.org

net stop w32time & net start w32time

w32tm /resync /force

w32tm /query /source

Answer (score 0):

I slightly tweaked NullReference's script to be able to be used as a startup task in an Azure web/worker role, and also synchronize every 6 hours:

```
REM   *** Change to use NTP for clock sync ***
%windir%\system32\reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\TimeProviders\VMICTimeProvider /v Enabled /t reg_dword /d 0 /f

%windir%\system32\reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\TimeProviders\NtpClient /v SpecialPollInterval /t reg_dword /d 21600 /f

%windir%\system32\w32tm /config /syncfromflags:manual /manualpeerlist:0.pool.ntp.org,1.pool.ntp.org,2.pool.ntp.org,3.pool.ntp.org

%windir%\system32\net stop w32time & net start w32time

%windir%\system32\w32tm /resync /force
```